# Properties of $A^TA$ transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Is it true a proposition for $3 \times 3$ real matrices $A$ that
if for a some nonzero vector $v$ we have $Av \neq v$ and at the same time $(A^TA)v=v$    then  for any vector $u$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have $(A^TA)u=u$ (i.e. $A$ is orthogonal) ?

Do we need assumption  about full rank of the matrix $A$ for this goal ?
Can we extend the proposition for bigger dimensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim fails even if $A$ is of full rank: for example, consider 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0 \\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\text{ and } \mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $A^TA = A^2$ and you can easily find $\mathbf{u}$ such that $A^TA\mathbf{u}\neq\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: I see, the examples are clear and contradict the proposition, I wonder however what additional assumption could be added to make the statement true..

Comment: @Widawensen Your claim holds if you can find an orthogonal basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ satisfying your condition. (i.e. $Av_i\neq v_i$ and $A^TAv_i = v_i$ for all $i=1,2,3$.)

Comment: So I need 3 vectors for that ? It is a little disappointing, I was hoping  maybe two were sufficient ...

Comment: @Widawensen Modifying my matrix (changing 1 in third row to -1) is a counterexample of your desired claim.

Comment: but what about if the matrix $A$ would not be symmetric ? would skew-symmetric component make a things different?

Comment: @Widawensen Any $3\times 3$ skew-symmetic matrix can't be of full rank. The answer might be positive if you consider $2\times 2$ skew-symmetric matrix, but it is better to ask your question as a separated question.

Comment: I was rather thinking about non-symmetric not pure skew-symmetric, anyway from Arnaud's solution also such the example can be elaborated..

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong.

Take any orthogonal matrix $M\in \Bbb R^{2\times 2}$, and extend it into a $3\times 3$ matrix using a column of ones and a row of zeroes:

$$\left[\matrix{\left[M\right] & \matrix{1\\1}\\ \matrix{0&0}&1}\right]$$

The result is not an orthogonal matrix, but it has full rank and even determinant $1$, and  most of the time $v=\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right)$ will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I've checked calculation at Wolfram Alpha with {transpose{{0.6,-0.8,1},{0.8,0.6,1},{0,0,1}}} *{{0.6,-0.8,1},{0.8,0.6,1},{0,0,1}}*{1,0,0} to receive however as the result  (1, 0, 1.4) so {1,0,0} seems to be not a good example.. I hope I've made no mistake in calculations..

Comment: More correctly    {transpose{{0.6,-0.8,1},{0.8,0.6,1},{0,0,1}}} *{{0.6,-0.8,1},{0.8,0.6,1},{0,0,1}}*{{1},{0},{0}} but the result is similar {{1},{0},{1.4}} ( as the matrix $A^TA$ is symmetric)

Comment: Generally for {{c,s,0},{-s,c,0},{1,1,1}}{{c,-s,1},{s,c,1},{0,0,1}}*{{1},{0},{0}} I've received {{c^2+s^2},{0}, {c+s}}

Comment: It seems that your method is good for $\cos a =-\sin a$..

Comment: In this case $A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & \sqrt{2}\\0 & \sqrt{2} & 3\end{bmatrix}$ where $A= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 1\\- \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 1\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @widawensen you are right!  First I had put zeroes instead of the ones on the right,  everything was fine but then I thought I could as well meet your requirements that the matrix is full-rank. But I overlooked it a bit I have to admit.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true. Take any symmetric matrix $A$ for which $-1$ is an eigenvalue; then if $v$ is an eigenvector for $-1$, we have $Av=-v\neq v$ but $A^TAv=A^2v=-Av=v$. But the other two eigenvalues could be anything, so the matrix need not be orthogonal. Note that this even works with $2\times 2$ matrices.